# Application Isolation with Linux Containers?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, docker, lxc

I am working on an embedded platform, where I have an important application which handles sensitive data. I want to protect this application from other application. For that I came up with containers.

---

I have set up a container in my Linux PC using LXC. I then run an application in the container. From the container, I can't access or see any application running in the host, but the reverse is possible (I could access the application in container from the host). Is there any way to isolate the container from the host machine? Are there any alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to isolate the container from the host machine?

No sorry. If you want to prevent other applications from accessing the data in the contained application, those other applications must be the one to be contained. The hypervisor will always have full access through all contained applications as it needs to do that to do its job.

Answer (score 2):

If one has access on the Host machine it will be possible to access the containers running in it.

What you could do is have a minimal Host installation, with no services running other than Docker and assign all your other services in container(s), keeping your app container isolated from other services.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things you could do. The better way would be to just run your app as a different user and don't give your main account any access to the extra user's folders and files. The second way would be to copy your entire system into a sub-folder and use chroot, but that is pretty difficult to set up and probably overkill.

Comment: We can access the chroot-ed application from the main (Host machine), Isn't that right. This is what i am trying to stop.

Comment: What I meant was: chroot your OS during boot time, not chroot your application.